# Share car(s) parking location with family members

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, maps, find-my

All family members have iPhones. We share 2 cars. What’s the best way to have the parked car location update automatically for everyone?

Currently I manually share the Parked Car location that appears in Maps after the phone disconnects from the car’s Bluetooth, but is there a way to automate that?

I thought about using AirTags but it’s not possible to share the location with other people (even if in the same iCloud family)…

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have old iPhones lying unused, you could leave them in the cars and share their locations with everyone involved.

Comment: Do car have CarPlay ? If yes you can create a automaton in shortcut to share car position with Shortcuts app

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Unfortunately I don’t have CarPlay or older iPhones…

Comment: The cheapest option would be 2 AirTags per car unfortunately, but that is kinda silly.

Comment: @PtitXav that's a very creative idea that I didn't think about!

Comment: Depending on iPhone model you could trigger a shortcut to execute when you double or triple tap on the back of your phone .this shortcut could share current location (May be you can share the car position from Plans app in a shortcut). The car location is saved when Bluetooth of car disconnect.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Creating a shortcut seems to be the best bet. I think it will work for me but I suspect some of my family members would struggle a little bit as they’re not as savvy. Strange that Apple hasn’t thought about this. Their engineers must all have a car each and all of their family members as well 